# Google cloud messaging registering and unregistering

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app using the new Google Cloud Messaging Framework. We know that once we register our app we get a registration id. But what happens when the user unistalls the app through the device for a number of times and re installs again and again (there is no new notification sent till now). Now with many installations done google might return several new registration ids and now all the ids are saved in the app database. 
If there is a notification to be sent it would be sent to all the ids previously saved also. Now my problem is that i think google is sending the notification to all the previous ids(so i get multiple notifications on the same device).

I hope i made my question clear and is there a solution to this.

Comment: I dont understand, an app has to be uninstalled before it can be installed again so the data should be gone on a new installation. you should be replacing the id on the server is there already is one for the user

Comment: The user can have multiple devices right and he can login through them.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a unique identifier to the app on each device. If you store that identifier on the external storage of this device, it won't be removed when the app is uninstalled. Then, when the app is installed again, you can send the registration ID along with that stored unique identifier. Your server will use the identifier to locate the old registration ID and replace it with the new one.

In addition, you should check for canonical registration IDs in the response you get from GCM. Each time to get a canonical ID, you should make sure you have that ID in your DB and remove the old ID (the one you used to send the message that got the canonical registration ID in its response).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if the data on the storage device becomes corrupted or is lost. Just had this question.

Comment: @user2525103 In that case you can only rely on the canonical registration ID returned by GCM to clean your DB. Your server might send the same message to the same device multiple times, but then you'll identify the old registration IDs and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the section **Canonical IDs** of the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html), as canonical IDs are specifically designed to solve your problem.

Every time you will send a message to an *old* registration ID Google will let you know what is the current canonical ID of the device you are sending a message to. Just make sure to replace your ID by this one.

Also make sure to check the code of the official demo [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java#108).